# Set specific font size for Hebrew characters in Word in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word, hebrew

I am in need to modify this code which is made for Word 2007 to Word XP. I need to set size for hebrew text in document. It is mix of Central Europe words combined with hebrew. What I need is hebrew text in bigger size. This contains only basic hebrew characters, no vowels. The non hebrews characters can be English or Czech (http://www.biega.com/special-char.html), the hebrew Chars are from 1488 to 1514.

But I could not run the code send here [Flag special characters in document using VBA in Word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42517802/flag-special-characters-in-document-using-vba-in-word) in the answer as I got error (Range?) object not selected.

```
Sub test()
    'Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdNoHighlight
    'Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdNoHighlight ' used for testing to clear Highlight

    Dim r As Range, t As Double: t = Timer
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each r In Range.Characters ' For Each r In Range.Words is somehow about 2 times slower than .Characters
        checkRange r
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Debug.Print Timer - t; Range.Words.Count; Range.Characters.Count; Range.End ' " 3.15625  8801  20601  20601 "
End Sub

Sub checkRange(r As Range)
    Dim b() As Byte, i As Long, a As Long
    b = r.Text ' converts the string to byte array (2 or 4 bytes per character)
    'Debug.Print "'" & r & "'"; r.LanguageID; r.LanguageIDFarEast; r.LanguageIDOther

    For i = 1 To UBound(b) Step 2            ' 2 bytes per Unicode codepoint
        If b(i) > 0 Then                     ' if AscW > 255
            a = b(i): a = a * 256 + b(i - 1) ' AscW
            Select Case a
                Case &H1F00 To &H1FFF: r.HighlightColorIndex = wdBlue: Exit Sub ' Greek Extended
                Case &H3040 To &H30FF: r.HighlightColorIndex = wdPink: Exit Sub ' Hiragana and Katakana
                Case &H4E00 To 40959: r.HighlightColorIndex = wdGreen: Exit Sub ' CJK Unified Ideographs

                Case 55296 To 56319: ' ignore leading High Surrogates ?
                Case 56320 To 57343: ' ignore trailing Low Surrogates ?

                Case Else: r.HighlightColorIndex = wdRed: Debug.Print Hex(a), r.End - r.Start ' other
            End Select
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

So I only need to select the size and make this working for Word XP. Any help?

Notice:
Whole document and the hebrew chars are written from left to right (when I typed hebrew in online keyboard, they were RTL, but after coping to Word they were LTR. But this was not problem, because I have copied/pasted them to display the hebrew word correctly. So they are in LTR in fact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because you haven't specified which object's range you want to process.

```
For Each r In Range.Characters
```

Needs to be qualified either as

```
For Each r In Selection.Range.Characters
```

or as

```
For Each r In ActiveDocument.Range.Characters
```

You could have answered this for yourself simply by looking up the online help for [`Range`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range)

NOTE:
Processing a document character by character is going to be a *very* long process. If the characters you want to process can be identified by language id you can speed up the process considerably.

Comment: Thank you so much. The result is very cool. I don't understand how could I simplify this for example grouping the hebrew word to some kind of object, and then to do some formating stuff. Of sure this is not the point of the main question, but maybe you know the terms I should look for in google to find some code for this.

Comment: @JohnBoe - the only thing that could realy help you is If the language has been set for the various parts of the document. In that case you can do what you want just using Find and Replace.